# Android Studio упала от переполнения диска. Теперь при открытии студии перестал самооткрыватся проект и раннее открытые файлы, как исправить?

Tags: android, android-studio

Так же пропали мои фильтры logcat, создаю их заново, но после закрытии студии они опять пропадают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папке своего проекта надо удалить поврежденный файл настроек
мойпроект\.idea\workspace.xml При следующем запуске студия его пересоздаст.